# Converting to and from Base64 using OpenSSL API

Tags: c++, base64, openssl

I am trying to get a working and good version of base64 conversions using OpenSSL. My alternatives were an implementation from an answer on SO and Boost (which I didn't chose because I read that is pretty broken).

I will need OpenSSL in my project and I thought it would be a good idea to use it for base64 too so I can get use with the API.

For start, let's just assume:

```
using ByteBuffer = std::vector<std::uint8_t>;
```

This is the header (`redi` is the main namespace of my project):

```
#ifndef REDI_BASE64_HPP
#define REDI_BASE64_HPP

#include "../bytebuffer.hpp"

namespace redi
{
namespace util
{
namespace base64
{

ByteBuffer encode(const ByteBuffer& data);
ByteBuffer encode(const std::string& str);
std::string encodeToString(const std::string& str);

ByteBuffer decode(const ByteBuffer& data);
ByteBuffer decode(const std::string& str);
std::string decodeToString(const ByteBuffer& data);
std::string decodeToString(const std::string& str);

} // namespace base64
} // namespace util
} // namespace redi


#endif // REDI_BASE64_HPP
```

and here is the source file:

```
#include <cassert>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <openssl/bio.h>
#include <openssl/buffer.h>
#include <openssl/evp.h>
#include "base64.hpp"

namespace redi
{
namespace util
{
namespace base64
{
namespace
{

void rawBase64Encode(const std::uint8_t* input, std::size_t inputLen, char*& output, std::size_t& outputLen)
{
  BIO* bio;
  BIO* b64;
  BUF_MEM* bufferPtr;

  b64 = BIO_new(BIO_f_base64());
  bio = BIO_new(BIO_s_mem());
  bio = BIO_push(b64, bio);

  BIO_set_flags(bio, BIO_FLAGS_BASE64_NO_NL);
  BIO_write(bio, input, static_cast<int>(inputLen));
  BIO_flush(bio);
  BIO_get_mem_ptr(bio, std::addressof(bufferPtr));
  BIO_set_close(bio, BIO_NOCLOSE);

  output = bufferPtr->data;
  outputLen = bufferPtr->length;
  free(bufferPtr);

  BIO_free_all(bio);
}

std::size_t calcDecodeLength(const std::uint8_t* input, std::size_t len)
{
  std::size_t padding = 0;

  if (input[len - 1] == '=')
  {
    ++padding;
    if (input[len - 2] == '=') ++padding;
  }

  return len * 3 / 4 - padding;
}

template <typename T>
void rawBase64Decode(const std::uint8_t* input, std::size_t inputLen, T& container)
{
  BIO* bio;
  BIO* b64;
  container.resize(calcDecodeLength(input, inputLen));

  bio = BIO_new_mem_buf(input, -1);
  b64 = BIO_new(BIO_f_base64());
  bio = BIO_push(b64, bio);

  BIO_set_flags(bio, BIO_FLAGS_BASE64_NO_NL);
  int l = BIO_read(bio, std::addressof(container[0]), static_cast<int>(inputLen));
  assert(static_cast<std::size_t>(l) == container.size());

  BIO_free_all(bio);
}

template <typename T, typename K>
T decodeInternal(const K& data)
{
  T result;
  rawBase64Decode(reinterpret_cast<const std::uint8_t*>(data.data()), data.size(), result);

  return result;
}

template <typename T, typename K>
T encodeInternal(const K& data)
{
  char* ptr = nullptr;
  std::size_t len = 0;
  rawBase64Encode(reinterpret_cast<const std::uint8_t*>(data.data()), data.size(), ptr, len);

  T result(ptr, len);
  free(ptr);

  return result;
}

}

ByteBuffer encode(const ByteBuffer& data)
{
  return encodeInternal<ByteBuffer, ByteBuffer>(data);
}

ByteBuffer encode(const std::string& str)
{
  return encodeInternal<ByteBuffer, std::string>(str);
}

std::string encodeToString(const std::string& str)
{
  return encodeInternal<std::string, std::string>(str);
}

ByteBuffer decode(const ByteBuffer& data)
{
  return decodeInternal<ByteBuffer, ByteBuffer>(data);
}

ByteBuffer decode(const std::string& str)
{
  return decodeInternal<ByteBuffer, std::string>(str);
}

std::string decodeToString(const ByteBuffer& data)
{
  return decodeInternal<std::string, ByteBuffer>(data);
}

std::string decodeToString(const std::string& str)
{
  return decodeInternal<std::string, std::string>(str);
}

} // namespace base64
} // namespace util
} // namespace redi
```

All of this has been "combined" from answers on SO and example on gist.

I would like to know if is a good design, if I can make any optimization (example: avoid copying the `char*` into the `ByteBuffer`, for instance) in encode, and, last but not least, if I have any memory leaks.

Comment: You are aware that published [templates must be implemented in the header file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file)? So is it really worth to use a template for the `std::string` and `ByteBuffer`?

Comment: Also note that [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/data) and [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/data) both support the `data()` member function (with the current standard). So I don't believe any copying of the buffer is necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I would like to know if is a good design

A few points about your design from a c++ perspective:

### 1. Usage of free functions instead of classes

From the point of OOP view, you should rather use classes than free functions to wrap / encapsulate the C API:

```
namespace redi
{
namespace util
{
namespace base64
{

    class Encoder {
    public:
        Encoder(const ByteBuffer& data);
        Encoder(const std::string& str);
        ByteBuffer operator(); // Do the encoding
        std::string to_string();
    };

    class Decoder {
    public:
        Decoder(const ByteBuffer& data);
        Decoder(const std::string& str);
        ByteBuffer operator(); // Do the decoding
        std::string to_string();
    };

} // namespace base64
} // namespace util
} // namespace redi
```

### 2. Prefer class specializations over introducing a `namespace`

Using classes as mentioned above you should prefer specializing classes (may be interface implementations) rather introducing a new `namespace` for a specific data category:

```
namespace redi
{
namespace util
{

    class Base64Encoder;
       // ^^^^^^
    class Base64Decoder;
       // ^^^^^^    
} // namespace util
} // namespace redi
```

Same for the function naming:

```
void rawBase64Encode(const std::uint8_t* input, std::size_t inputLen, char*& output, std::size_t& outputLen);
```

and

```
void rawBase64Decode(const std::uint8_t* input, std::size_t inputLen, T& container);
```

will become

```
void Base64Encoder::rawEncode();
```

and

```
void Base64Decoder::rawDecode();
```

as (probably `private`) class member functions.

### 3. Don't use `using` or `typedef` unnecessarily in published API's

The

```
using ByteBuffer = std::vector<std::uint8_t>;
```

obfuscates more, and leaves research efforts to API user, than it helps to save typing more code for the API provider.

Also I wouldn't provide that separately from the encoding / decoding features, but may be as a `public` `typedef` provided with classes.

### 4. In c++ encapsulate c-API handles

Your code all depends on a `BIO* bio;` API handle, at least internally

As mentioned above rather encapsulate that into a class. May be even into a common base class used for both, encoding and decoding:

```
 class Base64EncoderDecoderBase {
 protected:
      Bio* bio;
 };


 class Base64Encode : public Base64EncoderDecoderBase {
     // ...
 };

 class Base64Decode : public Base64EncoderDecoderBase {
     // ...
 };
```

### 5. Are you sure you need to use OpenSSL?

As suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5288179/1413395) are you sure you really need the OpenSS `Bio` structure, or that could be left to a simpler solution?

### 6. You probably don't need to copy

As mentioned in [my comment](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/151805/converting-to-and-from-base64-using-openssl-api#comment286420_151805) you probably don't need to have copies to interact with the OppenSSL library.
Using the `data()`members of these container classes directly, may be helpful to avoid that (not sure for the `Bio*` context though).

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I am going to apply your changes.